# "Move Module Members" with export default?

Tags: webstorm, intellij-14

I love WebStorm's "Move Module Members" feature, where I can move a function from one file into its own new file and all the imports and references are handled.

However, it creates the new file with the moved member as a *named export*. Is there any way to use this feature and have it create a default export? (`export default MovedMember`)

Obviously it can be changed after the fact, but it's a small pain to fix all the imports in other files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now it's not possible to modify the behavior of the **Move** refactoring. Please vote for this feature request: [WEB-44423](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44423)